# How do I edit this replacement code to only replace n line

Tags: python, python-3.x

the code I am working with essentially is supposed to go into a file ('Coincount.txt') and for nth line, if in its 4th portion (hence the 3) the string is equal to the variable named 'target', replace the fourth portion with the replacement.

```
import fileinput
if number_of_bags.is_integer():
    target, replacement = 'N', 'Y'
else:
    target, replacement = 'Y', 'N'

with fileinput.FileInput('CoinCount.txt', inplace=True) as fileobj:
    for n,line in enumerate(fileobj):
        words = line.rstrip().split(',')
        if words[3] == target:
            words[3] = replacement
        print(','.join(words))

    f = fileobj.lineno()  # Number of lines processed.
i = i + 1

print(f'Done, {f} lines processed')
```

also please know that the txt file is designed like such:

```
Abena,5p,325.00,Y
Malcolm,1p,3356.00,Y
Jane,£2,120.00,Y
Andy,£1,166.25,N
Sandip,50p,160.00,Y
Liz,20p,250.00,Y
Andy,20p,250.00,Y
Andy,50p,160.00,Y
Jane,£1,183.75,N
```

the 4th portion represents the 'Y' or 'N'

this is also apart of a bigger function but all that you need to know is that number_of_bags is a variable to the line that is being scanned which is how this thing works.

Please tell me how I need to restructure this code or implement a new line within it so that it works properly.

at the moment if I input this, the output in the txt file is:

```
Abena,5p,325.00,Y
Malcolm,1p,3356.00,Y
Jane,£2,120.00,Y
Andy,£1,166.25,Y
Sandip,50p,160.00,Y
Liz,20p,250.00,Y
Andy,20p,250.00,Y
```

this happens due to the `.join` as it replaces all of the 4th portions of the lines to `replacement`. I want to know how I can make this function only target nth line so that every line will either replace the 4th portion or will just leave it if it is already input correctly.

Comment: instead of playing with text, use csv module, it will make life easy for you.

Comment: What my understanding is, you want to replace `Y` and `N` right ? if you can give what is your input, and what is your expected output, that will help to solve your things.

Comment: it reads exactly the same as a csv file as they are split

Answer (score 0):

if i get your question right you want to only change one line that, so lets say you have this:

```py
line_to_replace = 3 # var that will incidate what line you want to change
```

so you can change your code:

```py
for n,line in enumerate(fileobj):
```

into:

```py
for n,line in enumerate(fileobj):
    if n == line_to_replace: # simple if to check the current line number
        ...code...
```

Comment: when I add in the code you given me, it goes through each line but the first lines code turns all of the text file to one line and then the next line it goes through it comes out with 0 lines in the text file.

Comment: @Editsxo its not what your question show as example

Comment: what do you mean? I explained within my question that the program goes through each line individually, please understand the code I have put forward before coming up with a solution.